# syntax error and immediate closing of window

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I try to code a simple program in Python the window disappears immediately. This is the code:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> print('hello')
hello
>>> print('hello')
hello
>>> raw_input('press enter to close')
press enter to close
```

Comment: Were you trying to run an interpreter session as if it were a script?

Comment: That is no program but an interpreter session, and the only way for it to "disappear" would be for the interpreter to crash and take the terminal down with it. What exactly is your "program", and how exactly did you run it? Double-clicked the `.py` file or something?

Comment: Try to change the extension of your file from `.py` to `.pyw` which is executed by `pythonw.exe`.

Comment: @viach done that! didn't worked.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes it was a script. i saved it and tried to run it.i am just two days old in python and i've never don programing before i don't know what a interpreter session is but will like to know.can you please explain?thnx

Comment: @tobias_k- yeah
yeah my code was
print('hello')
raw_input('press enter to close')

i know it's dumb m a newbee and trying to learn and
ummm_hmm i double clicked the .py file
thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you don't also have Python 3 installed? If your script is being run by Python 3, `raw_input` is no more in Python 3, and trying to use it would cause an error, so you could try to replace it with `input`.

Comment: no i'm pretty sure of that but i previously had it on my system
i uninstalled it later
does it matter?